# Passing value from TK to a file and replacing a variable

Tags: sed, tk-toolkit

I am trying to interface between tk and cshell-script.
I am able to collect data using tk:

```
label .firstColumn.s.variable.label -text "myFirstVariable" -background $color3
entry .firstColumn.s.variable.entry -textvariable program
```

But when I try to run the command it does not work

```
button .secondColumn.o.buttons.go -text "Run Now" \
    -command "exec sed -i {s/ABC/$myFirstVariable/g} runme.sh \
    >! runmeNow.sh ; ./runmeNow"
```

It changes `ABC` to blank in `runmeNow.sh` file.

Is there any better way to achieve it?
I want to replace a place-holder predefined in cshell-script (`runme.sh`). My place holder is `ABC`. Then I want to pipe it to a different file, then run this file. `runme.sh` has UNIX based run file.

Comment: Try re-formatting your question, something seems off with it... Pretty hard to get what you mean also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SED in TCL/TK and any other equivalent command in TCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048523/sed-in-tcl-tk-and-any-other-equivalent-command-in-tcl)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that tk is interpreting `$myFirstVariable` as a variable of its own, while you'd like it to be forwarded to shell. Escaping the dollar sign with a backslash may not be enough: `exec` is a Tcl command  and doesn't use a shell, so we may have to call one to expand shell variable:

```
button .secondColumn.o.buttons.go -text "Run Now" \
    -command "exec /bin/sh -i {sed "s/ABC/$myFirstVariable/g" runme.sh \
    > runmeNow.sh ; ./runmeNow.sh}"
```

Comment: Qeole, Thanks for the reply. I tried simplifying myFirstVariable and changed it to bozo1 but it still does not work. If you guys have used similar tk expression/function , will you mind posting it here please.

Comment: @user3889479 Why are you using sed `-i` option? It edits `runme.sh` in place, and produces no output on standard output, so it seems normal that nothing is redirected to `runmeNow.sh`. Does `... -command "exec sed {s/ABC/\$myFirstVariable/g} runme.sh"` print expected output? Also I don't know cshell-script, is it different from classic shell? Have you tried `>` instead of `>!`?

Comment: I am new to scripting... sed does replace ABC with blank, so it looks like it is not reading $myFisrtVariable. On top it does not direct the file to runmenow.sh.  What I am trying to do is to grab user's input and pass it to a predefined template for shell-script and run the script .  If there is possible solution, then please let me know.

Comment: I've edited my solution, seems to work for me at least for the `sed` part. The `$myFirstVariable` is a shelle variable, isn't it? Or should it be a Tcl/Tk variable?